# Laravel 5 Global Scope with Dynamic Parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

We're having issues using a global scope with a dynamic query parameter.  The global scope is based on the manager ID, but $model is empty, and $this refers to the manager scope not the model so $this->id is an undefined property. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    return $builder->where('manager', $model->id); // $this->id
}
```

I'm assuming that `$model` is supposed to be the manager model, but since it is empty and I can't find any documentation on it I'm not entirely sure (if anyone can tell me in a comment I'd appreciate it).  This is our global scope method in the Manager model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new ManagerScope);
}
```

Since global scopes don't require an explicit method to be applied I thought maybe adding something to the boot might allow for an extra parameter something like:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope(new ManagerScope($this->id);
}
```

But this isn't allowed in a static method, which makes sense after I saw the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Naturally global scopes are applied automatically and there are no way to pass parameters to them directly.

Therefore you can either stick with a dynamic local scope, which IMO makes more sense,

```php
public function scopeForManager($query, $manager)
{
    return $query->where('manager', $manager->id);
}

Document::forManager($manager)->all();
```

or if the a manager info is available in some kind of global state (i.e. session) you can create some sort of ManagerResolver class

```php
class ManagerScope
{
    protected $resolver;

    public function __construct(ManagerResolver $resolver)
    {
        $this->resolver = $resolver
    }

    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->where('manager', $this->resolver->getManagerId());
    }    
}
```

and pass an instance of it into your scope

```php
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::addGlobalScope(new ManagerScope(new ManagerResolver());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, we actually do have a deferred service provider that is used to get the currently authenticated user, in this case the manager, from a token in middleware so this might work.  The reason we didn't want to use a local scope was to avoid developers mistakes that forgot to use it since that would be an issue for applicant security, but I guess it could be directly chained to the applicants relationship.  Can you explain what $model should be used for?  I can't find an example that makes sense.

Comment: Built-in `SoftDeletingScope` would be a good example where `$model` is used to figure out a fully qualified name of of "`deleted_at`" column for a table that holds model data because you can override the method that returns the name of that column in your model.

Comment: Did it help in any way?

Answer (score 1):

Update for Laravel 8.x

You can create a static function inside your model and then use it in a created scope. For example, let's say that you want to create a global search for all tables without creating a search function for each model.

In your scope class do the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
 
class SearchScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        if(!empty($keyword = \request()->query('q')))
            $builder->where($model::searchField(), 'LIKE', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    }
}
```

Then create searchField() function in every model like this:

```
    <?php
    namespace Modules\Api\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Scopes\SearchScope;
    
    class Product extends Model
    {
        protected static function searchField(){
            return "products.name"; // Name of field to be used in WHERE clause while searching using LIKE operator
        } 
    
        protected static function booted()
        {
            static::addGlobalScope(new SearchScope);
        }
}
```

Bravo! Now you can use a dynamic variable in Laravel scope!!

Comment: Clever use of static function

Comment: What does the `!empty($keyword = \request()->query('q'))` part do? And is there a way to get the keyword dynamically from the model? I'm trying to build something similar to the `softDelete` but need to have information from the model

Comment: That was for example. The global scope is applied only if keyword is passed in $request. The problem here is just how to pass additional variables in apply() method so that they can be used by Builder