# Extending Eloquent Models with dynamic global scopes

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a MySQL table that receives many different Jotform reports in JSON payloads. This has helped tremendously in capturing queryable data quickly without adding to the front-end developer's workload.

I created an eloquent model for the table. I now would like to be able to create models that extend it for each Jotform we create. I feel like it will increase the readability of my code drastically.

My eloquent model is called `RawDataReport`. It has `created_at`, `updated_at`, `data`, and `report name` columns in the table. I want to create the model `ShiftInspectionReport` extending the `RawDataReport`.

I have two JotForm reports one is called `Shift Inspection Report` and one is called `Need Inspection Report`. Both are part of the `ShiftInspectionReport` model.

So I need to query the `RawDataReports` table for any reports matching those names. I frequently need to query the `RawDataReports` `report_name` column with either one or more report names.

To help with this I created a local scope to query the report name which accepts either a string report name or an array of string report names.  Here is the local scope on the `RawDataReports` model.

```php
protected function scopeReportName($query, $report_name): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
{
    if (is_array($report_name)) {
        return $query->orWhere(function ($query) USE ($report_name) {
            ForEach($report_name as $report) {
                if (is_string($report) === false) {
                    throw new \Exception('$report_name must be an array of strings or a string');
                }
    
                $query->where('report_name', $report);
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (is_string($report_name) === false) {
            throw new \Exception('$report_name must be an array of strings or a string');
        }

        return $query->where('report_name', $report_name);
    }
}
```

EDIT - after comments I simplified the reportName scope

```
    protected function scopeReportName($query,array $report_name): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
    {
        return $query->whereIn('report_name',$report_name);
    }
```

Now in my `ShiftInspectionReport` model, I'd like to add a global scope that can use that local scope and pass in the $report_name.  But according to this article, [Laravel 5 Global Scope with Dynamic Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39277768/laravel-5-global-scope-with-dynamic-parameter), it doesn't look like Laravel global scopes allow you to use dynamic variables.

I could just create a local scope in `ShiftInspectionReport` but the readability would look like

```php
$reports = ShiftInspectionReport::shiftInspectionReport()->startDate('2021-05-15')->get()
```

when I'd really like to be able to just call

```php
ShiftInspectionReport::startDate('2021-05-15')->get()
```

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: If `startDate(date)` is a scope, you could make it call the `shiftInspectionReport()` scope in the method itself. `public function scopeStartDate(Builder $query, $date) { return $query->shiftInspectionReport()->....; })`

Comment: Or, since `shiftInspectionReport()` doesn't seem to have any parameters, you could make it a global scope for the `ShiftInspectionReport` model.

Comment: By the way isn't your `scopeReportName()` scope  just an `orWhereIn()` ?

Comment: Now that you mention it `orWhereIn()` does sound much better and I don't see why I can't simplify it to use that instead.  Thank you!  You did solve my problem though, I feel silly now.  I didn't realize I could just call the local scope from the base class when declaring the global scope.  I thought because it was in the boot function that I didn't have access to the scopes I declare at that point.

Comment: if a class extends from another, it has access to all of its parents methods

Comment: IGP, right just wasn't sure if that was the case given that laravel's scoped methods are accessed as magic methods.  So I foolishly assumed I wouldn't have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to IGP I figured out that I can just call the local scope right from my boot function.

My extended class looks like this now and it works.

```
class ShiftInspection extends RawDataReport
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('shift_inspection_report', function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->reportName(['Shift Safety Inspection','Need Safety Inspection']);
        });
    }
}
```